# CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage with NULL Range

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to use `CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage`. The docs say:

> The range of string to use for the test. If NULL, the first few hundred characters of the string are examined.

But passing `NULL` yields an error:

> Passing 'void *' to parameter of incompatible type 'CFRange'

What is the correct way of doing this?

`NSString *language = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage((CFStringRef)text, NULL));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an error in the documentation.

`NULL` is typically defined as something like

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)
```

so it's a pointer.

On the other hand `CFRange` is defined as

```
struct CFRange {
   CFIndex location;
   CFIndex length;
};
typedef struct CFRange CFRange;
```

so it's a struct, i.e. a non-pointer type.

A struct cannot be assigned to `NULL`, since they have incompatible types, therefore technically speaking a `CFRange` cannot be `NULL`.

Back to your specific problem, you may want to do something like

```
CFStringRef text = //your text
CFRange range = CFRangeMake(0, MIN(400, CFStringGetLength(text)));
NSString *language = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage(text, range));
```

I picked 400 since the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringTokenizerRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage) states

> Typically, the function requires 200-400 characters to reliably guess the language of a string.

---

**UPDATE**

I reported the error to Apple.

Comment: Cool this is the solution I came to as well but was thrown off by the docs.